# Right align an icon in Bootstrap 4 modal title

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to place two icons next to the close button in the Bootstrap 4 modal. However, there's some margin-left which I'm unable to remove it. In inspect element, I manage to get it done but when I apply that to the .close or button class, it doesn't work!

**DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/x2m3kfzu/**

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&copy;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.close, button {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://jsfiddle.net/9exbr8ny/

Comment: I will accept @sudhansu bhatta's answer. It's simple but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the buttons inside a div.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <div>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&copy;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please see the .modal-header CSS.It has `display: flex;justify-content: space-between;.`.  So what it does is place the child elements inside the div with the same gap between them.